# Can someone tell me why I get this error message? inline constexpr variable

Tags: c++, inline

I follow a tutorial from here https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/global-constants-and-inline-variables/

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "constants.h"
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter a radius: ";
    int radius{};
    std::cin >> radius;

    std::cout << "The circumference is: " << 2 * radius * constants::pi;
    return 0;
}
```

constants.h

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

// define your own namespace to hold constants
namespace constants
{
    inline constexpr double pi { 3.14159 }; // note: now inline constexpr
    inline constexpr double avogadro { 6.0221413e23 };
    inline constexpr double my_gravity { 9.2 }; // m/s^2 -- gravity is light on this planet
    // ... other related constants
}
#endif
```

error message g++11:

```
error: 'constants::pi' declared as an 'inline' variable
```

Comment: _C++17 introduced a new concept called inline variables._

Comment: Inline variables are introduced in C++17. Are you using C++17, e.g. `-std=c++17`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inline variables are allowed starting from C++17.

You need to specify the `-std=c++17` option on the
compiler command line.

( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline )